# Increase the size of my ubuntu 12.04 (dual boot) partition

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, ubuntu-12.04

I'm currently dual booting Mac OS X Mountain Lion and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I'd like to shrink my mac partition by 10 GB and increase my Ubuntu partition by 10 GB, preferably by maintaining the data on both partitions.

I'm familiar with the process of reducing partitions in (mac) disk utility, and then booting into Ubuntu and reformatting that partition; but how do I resize an existing Ubuntu partition without repartitioning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking but then again it could be just me. The first thing that comes to mind for me is to simply use Partition magic or GParted. You can just simply boot into them and resize to what you like but I would recommend backing up the partitions before anything to prevent data loss.

Comment: GParted might be all I'm looking for... I'll look into it and get back to you, thanks Cyberdyne!